# save the guest address without placing an order

Tags: customer-account, shipping-address

we have a magento site with version 1.9

some guest added some items to the cart and than they entered

the shipping information and they select payment method and than they will not place order.

they will close the site.

is there any way , so that after guest entered the shipping address

we have to save that shipping address in the admin panel or in the database....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file change **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml**

For guest  magento have it **customer_id as null**.So you need to **sales model by guest email address** and magento set a **flagcustomer_is_guest =1**whenever customer will checkout as guest.

Magento also save Customer email address to sales model table whenever loggin customers are checkout ,so on this case **customer_is_guest =1** is importand

```
  $orderCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$Customeremail)
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_is_guest',1) ->addFieldToSelect('*');
foreach( $orderCollection  as $eachorder){
//var_dump($eachOrder)
}
```

Comment: can you please inform me in which file path and file name i have to update the above code

Comment: i added the above code at the bottom of the file.  and i tried guest checkout, i entered billing and shipping information, but when i checked in admin panel , Managae customers, it did't saved the guest address.

Comment: what mistake i did , what else i have to do?

Comment: clear magento cashe and reindex

Comment: please check this info.phtml at the bottom of this file = > http://pastebin.com/rA0fh35w

Comment: helpful question:-http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10180/how-to-save-customer-name-for-guest-checkout